# What is the opposite of the "green thumb" but for technology/electronics?

Tags: analogy

As having a green thumb is someone who is good with plants, jokingly, the brown thumb could be used for someone who is bad with plants.

Is there an equivalent pair for being good/bad with technology/electronics?

Comment: If you're in the mood for inventing a pairing where none exists, I always liked the contrast between being a *hacker* and being unable to *hack it*. Are you looking for a strict contrast (green / brown thumb), or just two distinct terms?

Comment: The opposite of having a green thumb is being a PEBCAK.

Comment: Does this include  "electronics" in the sense of taking apart and fixing something, or only a person who can punch buttons  competently? I had a friend who used to brag about how many "extra" parts he always had left over....

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin just looking for the contrasting term, not necessarily a pair. A one-word opposite would be nice, but seems there is none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone who is good with technology/electronics -

## Computer-literate

> : (of a person) having sufficient knowledge and skill to be able to use computers; familiar with the operation of computers.

([Source](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/computer_literate))

---

So if you aren't specifically looking for an idiom, I'd suggest -

## Computer-illiterate

which, of course, would be the opposite of *computer-literate*.

---

You could also say that the person is "***technologically inept***".

---

You could also say -

## Luddite

> : A Luddite is someone who is incompetent when using new technology.

([Source 1](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Luddite))

([Source 2](http://www.wordthink.com/luddite/))

---

**EDIT**

Removed ***tech-savvy*** as it appeared to be quite informal.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that definition of *Luddite*.  I've only heard it used to refer to the Industrial Revolution Luddites and, by extension, people who dislike modern technologies and discourage their use.

Comment: I kept researching and that's what kept coming up. But I did find a source that suggests a meaning in line with the OP's context. It does look like a reputable site, though. Downvotes are still welcome. (Oh... And I had the same thoughts as you too.)

Comment: It's unfortunate that one suggestion is an adjective and the other is a noun...

Comment: I don't think this answer deserves a downvote.  I may not have encountered that definition, but it seems someone has.

Comment: Complaining about downvotes is [a waste of time.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12126/looking-for-valid-reasons-for-the-downvote-to-this-question/13135#13135)@Juhasz

Comment: @Juhasz - I've heard *Luddite* used this way quite a few times, where in context it was fairly clear that this meaning was intended rather than the original meaning.

Comment: Is it still possible to use “tech-savvy” in a non-ironic way?

Comment: -1 Use a standard dictionary for meanings and use cases. Good Luck.

Comment: I think of "luddite" as meaning someone who prefers not to use modern technology, not necessary inept at it. I'm tech savvy, but I still use a flip-phone, so I consider my self a cellphone luddite.

Comment: @Barmar - I have changed my answer as *luddite* wasn't being accepted well.

Comment: Hmm luddite seemed quite good to me, to elaborate a bit on the background, a friend of mine whom I occasionally lend electronic devices ends up breaking them, but just through regular use and unintentionally.

Comment: @Horst - Added *luddite* back to my answer.

Comment: @horst - well, in that case, he's a tech shlemiel.

Answer (score 0):

The person who is a natural with computers is a

[**hacker**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hacker)

> (Merriam-Webster) 3: an expert at programming and solving problems with a computer

The person who is a disaster with computers is a

[**technophobe**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/technophobe)

> technophobia : fear or dislike of advanced technology or complex devices and especially computers

Comment: Not looking for disliking technology, but rather being bad at using it/breaking it unintentionally.

Comment: Your definition for "hacker" refers to "an expert" - that is somewhat beyond merely "being *good with technology*", which is what the Q. asked for. I would regard myself as being *good with technology* - but certainly **not** a "hacker"! There's a huge gap between being ***good** with technology* and being a hacker!

Answer (score -1):

For technology generally, a somewhat old-fashined term of being bad at it is [all thumbs.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all-thumbs) Due to modern [texting,](https://www.verbling.com/discussion/idioms-what-does-the-phrase-im-all-thumbs-mean) this has taken on a different meaning of being proficient at typing with your thumbs.

[The knack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8vHhgh6oM0) is a term that Scott Adams took to mean "having great engineering ability." So "lost his knack" is an engineer who has lost the ability to do engineering.